# Use of if-then-else inside neural network diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to use the if-then-else statement to draw \vdots instead of a node.
In the following diagram:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\def\layersepp{5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep,]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {}; % {$p_\y$};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
        \path[yshift=0.cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
        \path[yshift=0.cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H1-\name) at (\layersepp,-\y cm) {};


    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H1-3] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
            \path (H-\source) edge (H1-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
        \path (H1-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,above of=H1-1, node distance=1cm] (hl1) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl1] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

plots this figure:

[image]

To remove the penultimate (4th) node in the three first columns of nodes I use `\ifthenelse` with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep,]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5} 
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \ifthenelse{\NOT 4 = \y }{
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {}; % {$p_\y$};
        }{$\vdots$}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
      \ifthenelse{\NOT 4 = \y }{
        \path[yshift=0.cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};
      }{$\vdots$}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
      \ifthenelse{\NOT 4 = \y }{
        \path[yshift=0.cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H1-\name) at (\layersepp,-\y cm) {};
      }{$\vdots$}

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H1-3] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
        \ifthenelse{\NOT 4 = \y }{
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);
        }{}

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
        \ifthenelse{\NOT 4 = \y }{
            \path (H-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
        }{}

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
      \ifthenelse{\NOT 4 = \y }{
        \path (H1-\source) edge (O);
        }{}

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,above of=H1-1, node distance=1cm] (hl1) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl1] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it does not compile, giving the following error in the first `ifthenelse`

`Latex Error: ./rnn_split_2.tex:103 Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you cannot put `\vdots` into the middle of a `tizpicture` environment. Instead, you need to put this inside a node. That is something like `\node at (0,0) {$\vdots$};`. Another issue is that "long" `\foreach` statements need to be enclosed in braces. To be on the safe side, I always write

```
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5} {
...
}
```

Some of your tests involving `\y` should have been tests with `\dest` or `\source`. Apart from this I have used a straight `\ifnum\y=4 ...\else ...\fi` since I prefer this. Making these changes your code compiles and produces:

[image]

Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepackage{xifthen}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\def\layersepp{5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep,]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5} {
        \ifnum\y=4 \node at (0,-\y) {$\vdots$}; % {$p_\y$};
        \else
          \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {}; % {$p_\y$};
        \fi
    }

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5} {
        \ifnum\y=4 \node at  (\layersep,-\y cm) {$\vdots$}; % {$p_\y$};
        \else
          \path[yshift=0.cm] node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};
        \fi
    }

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5} {
        \ifnum\y=4 \node at  (\layersepp,-\y cm) {$\vdots$}; % {$p_\y$};
        \else
          \path[yshift=0.cm] node[hidden neuron] (H1-\name) at (\layersepp,-\y cm) {};
        \fi
    }

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H1-3] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5} {
        \ifnum\source=4\else
          \foreach \dest in {1,...,5} {
            \ifnum\dest=4\else
              \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);
            \fi
          }
        \fi
    }

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5} {
      \ifnum\source=4\else
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5} {
          \ifnum\dest=4\else
              \path (H-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
          \fi
        }
      \fi
    }

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5} {
      \ifnum\source=4\else
        \path (H1-\source) edge (O);
      \fi
    }

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,above of=H1-1, node distance=1cm] (hl1) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl1] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Finally, `\tiksstyle` has been depreciated. These days you should use `\tikzset`, but I didn't change this.